# Group structure of given $2\times 2$ matrix group over $\mathbb{F}_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory

I want to determine the group structure of
$$G=\left.\left\{ \left(\begin{array}{cc} a & c \\ 0 & b \end{array}\right) \;\right|\;  a,b \in \mathbb{F}_3^{×}, c \in \mathbb{F}_3\right\}.$$

My try:

The order of $G$ is $2\cdot 2\cdot 3＝12$.
And I checked this is not abelian, so **this group is isomorphic to $D_{12}$ or $Q_{12}$ or $A_4$**. **I want to decide which one is.** For now, I calculated the order of elements of $G$. There are $2$ elements of order $6$, $2$ elements of order $3$, $7$ elements of order $2$, $1$ elements of order $1$ (if my calculation is right).

Comment: How can there be $3$ elements of order $3$? And you have listed the orders of $3+7+1=11$ elements. What is the order of the last one?

Comment: Have you determined the orders of the elements of the three remaining groups? Or some other distinguishing feature(s)?

Comment: (Servaes' point here is that elements of order $3$ always come in in pairs. If $x$ has order $3$, then so does $x^2$.)

Comment: Somewhat [related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2615211).

Comment: Sorry, I modified.

Comment: Your counts of elements of given orders is wrong. There are only two of order $3$, for example, and some have order $6$.

Comment: The subgroup $H$ of $G$ consisting of matrices with $c=1$ form a non-abelian group of order six, meaning that you can positively identify $H$. Obviously also $H\unlhd G$. That narrows down the possibilities, I think.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen That's not a subgroup, it's not closed under multiplication. Did you mean $b=1$?

Comment: It's easier just to note that the matrices with determinant $1$ form a cyclic subgroup of order $6$. (If you take $b=1$, you get a dihedral subgroup of order $6$.)

Comment: @Derek Holt  You mean, $G$ is isom to $D_6$(order 12) ?

Comment: @ancientmathematician Absolutely! Who gave the asker the permission to write the matrix entries in a non-alphabetical order :-)

Comment: @kleinfour Unfortunately some people denote the dihedral group of order $2n$ by $D_{2n}$ and others by $D_n$. You seem to have used $D_{2n}$ in your post and $D_n$ in your comment, which is very confusing - please be consistent. I haven't used either notation, and I  did not say explicitly that $G$ is isomorphic to the dihedral group of order $12$. I was hoping that you could deduce that yourself from my comments.

Answer (score 2):

You have already determined that $G$ is isomorphic to one of $D_{12}$, $Q_{12}$ or $A_4$. You have also determined that $G$ has two elements of order $6$. As $A_4$ has no elements of order $6$, this option is eliminated.

The group $Q_{12}$ has an element of order $4$, but $G$ has no elements of order $4$. This eliminates $Q_{12}$, and so $G\cong D_{12}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Question:** I want to determined group structure of
$$G=\left.\left\{ \left(\begin{array}{cc} a & c \\ 0 & b \end{array}\right) \;\right|\;  a,b \in \mathbb{F}_3^{×}, c \in \mathbb{F}_3\right\},$$

**Answer:** For finite non-abelian groups of matrices over finite fields one tries to realize the group as a semi direct product of smaller abelian groups:

Let

$$H=\left.\left\{ \left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & c \\ 0 & 1 \end{array}\right) \;\right|\;  c \in \mathbb{F}_3\right\} \cong \mathbb{F}_3,$$

and

$$N=\left.\left\{ \left(\begin{array}{cc} a & 0 \\ 0 & b \end{array}\right) \;\right|\;  a,b \in \mathbb{F}_3^*\right\} \cong (\mathbb{F}_3^*)^2 \cong (\mathbb{Z}/(2))^2.$$

It follows for any $g\in G, h\in H$ that $ghg^{-1}\in H$ hence $H \subseteq G$ is a normal subgroup and the action $\sigma$ of  $G$ on $H$ is via the character  $\rho:G \rightarrow \mathbb{F}_3^*$ defined by $\rho(g):=a/b$.
You get an action

$$\sigma: G \times H \rightarrow H$$

defined by

$$\sigma(g,x):= \rho(g)x:=\frac{a}{b}x \text{ with $x\in \mathbb{F}_3$ and $a,b\in \mathbb{F}_3^*$ }.$$

Since $NH=G$ and $N\cap H=\{e\}$ you may express $G$ as a semi direct product

$$G \cong N \rtimes H \cong (\mathbb{F}_3^*)^2 \rtimes_{\rho(-)} \mathbb{F}_3     \cong (\mathbb{Z}/(2))^2 \rtimes_{\rho(-)} \mathbb{Z}/(3).$$

This express $G$ as a semi direct product of two known abelian groups - maybe this is helpful classifying the group. I'm not familiar with the groups you write down - you should check if this group is one on the list.

**Note 1:** It seems the alternating group $A_4$ sits in an exact sequence

$$0 \rightarrow (\mathbb{Z}/(2))^2 \rightarrow A_4 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/(3) \rightarrow 0,$$

and this may imply there is an isomorphism $G \cong A_4$. It should be possible to write down an explicit isomorphism.

**Another approach:** You may define the subgroup

$$H_1=\left.\left\{ h:=\left(\begin{array}{cc} u & x \\ 0 & 1 \end{array}\right) \;\right|\;  u\in \mathbb{F}_3^*, x \in \mathbb{F}_3\right\} \cong \mathbb{F}_3^* \rtimes \mathbb{F}_3 ,$$

and $H_1 \subseteq G$ is another normal subgroup and you get an exact sequence

$$ 0 \rightarrow H_1 \rightarrow G \rightarrow  \mathbb{Z}/(2) \rightarrow 0.$$

As commented: The group $H_1 \cong \mathbb{F}_3^* \rtimes \mathbb{F}_3$ is a non-trivial semi direct product of $\mathbb{F}_3 \cong \mathbb{Z}/(3)$ and $\mathbb{F}_3^* \cong \mathbb{Z}/(2)$ hence is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/(6)$. The group $\mathbb{F}_3^*$ acts canonically on $\mathbb{F}_3$ via multiplication. Hence $H_1$ is non-abelian.

If you look at the subgroup

$$ N_1=\left.\left\{ g:=\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & b \end{array}\right) \;\right|\;  b\in \mathbb{F}_3^* \right\} \cong \mathbb{Z}/(2),$$

it follows $N_1$ acts as follows:

$$ghg^{-1}=\left(\begin{array}{cc} a & x/b \\ 0 & 1 \end{array}\right)$$

hence $g$ acts "through inversion". There is a semi direct product $G \cong H_1 \rtimes N_1$.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product#Inner_semidirect_product_definitions

Comment: Why order of $G$ is $6$ ? $G$ 's determinant is not supposed to be $1$, so there are two $b$ for given $a$. $b$ is not defined as inverse of $a$, why you assume $b$ is inverse of $a$ ?

Comment: Great answer. I'm just a bit confused about the nomenclature. Why is the letter $N$ used for the diagonal matrices while the *other one* is the one that is normal (and usually called in $N$ in the context of Lie theory)?

Comment: I ask about about 'note'  second one from the bottom. $A_4$ has $4$ conjugacy class, but $G$ has $6$ conjugacy class ( 4 $1$ -dimensional irreducible rep and $2$ 2-dimmensional rep).

Comment: I think $G$ and $A_4$ cannot be isom because it's number of conjugacy classes is different.

Comment: @hm2020 Many people denote the dihedral group of order $2n$ by $D_{2n}$ rather than $D_n$, and since the poster was talking about groups of order $12$, it seemed clear that $D_{12}$ was intended to be dihedral of order $12$.

Comment: @hm2020 Sorry, I'm confused. Number of conjugacy class of $G$ is $4$ or $6$ ?(I believe $6$, and you claim it is $4$ ? )

Comment: So for a quick solution, note that $G$ is a nonabelian group of order $12$ with a cyclic subgroup of order $6$ and no element of order $4$. The dihedral group is the only example with those properties.

Comment: @hm2020 I'm confused. I think $G$ is isom to $D_6$ and it is not isom to $A_4$. Your note second from the bottom is wrong, isn't it ?

Comment: @kleinfour - the above aproach shows how you may locate normal subgroups of matrix groups over finite fields and how to write a group as an extension of two smaller abelian groups. When classifying groups you may use this approach. There are of course more elementary approaches as indicated inthis thread.

Comment: Your subgroup $H_1$ is not abelian.

Answer (score 1):

I think that concentrating on the case $p=3$ and special properties of groups of order $12$ isn't really very illuminating.

So let $p$ be an odd prime. Consider the group
$$G=
\left\{ 
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b\\
0 & d
\end{pmatrix}
\ :\ 
a,d\in\mathbb{F}_p^{*},\ \ b\in\mathbb{F}_p
\right\}
$$
which is clearly of order $p(p-1)^2$.

Then the centre of the whole matrix group $Z=
\left\{ 
\begin{pmatrix}
a & 0\\
0 & a
\end{pmatrix}
\ :\ 
a\in\mathbb{F}_p^{*}
\right\}
$ is a cyclic subgroup of $G$ of order $(p-1)$; and so it is a normal subgroup lying in the centre of $G$.

Moreover $G$ has a subgroup $H=\left\{ 
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b\\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\ :\ 
a\in\mathbb{F}_p^{*},\ \ b\in\mathbb{F}_p
\right\}$ of order $p(p-1)$ which intersects $Z$ trivially, and is normalised by the  central $Z$, and so by all of $G$.

Hence $G=Z\times H$.

The group $H$ is known as the affine group: it is clearly isomorphic to the set of mappings $\mathbb{F}_p\to\mathbb{F}_p$ of the form $\{x\mapsto ax+b \mid a,b\in\mathbb{F}_p, a\ne 0\}$.

In the case $p=3$ we clearly have $G=C_2\times S_3$.

Comment: This is essentially the same idea as in my post - locate a normal subgroup and construct the quotient. But how does this classify the group $G$? Which of the 3 groups of this type has this decomposition $Z \times H$?